# how to store log file when loading data in database in mysql

Tags: mysql, unix, load-data-infile

```
mysql -uabc -pabc -DDesk -e"LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tmp/discounts.txt'INTO TABLE discounts FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';" database > abc/cde/test.log

Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

From this MySQL loading, I'm trying to load everything in a log file like after executed this query if any error found or after successful execution the result like how many rows insert in DB which we show in the os console. But I'm unable to catch the log file, Is it possible to store log related file, please help

Answer (score 0):

```
SET global general_log_file='/temp/detail.log'; 
SET global log_output = 'file';
SET global general_log = on;
```

then while you execute queries it will store all .
Obviusly this will slow down a little bit the server but it provide the requested log file.

Comment: It's working successfully but in my case log file generated for other MySQL users, I don't have permission to access those log file, Is there any other way to generate the same log?

Comment: maybe store the log in a different path where you have access

Comment: I have 777 access in the path where I'm storing the log file

Comment: so i don't understand what you mean for " I don't have permission to access those log file"

Comment: Let assume I have 2 users on the server, I'm logging into the server using user "a" and connecting MySQL DB from this user but when executing the script it's generating the log file with access permission of user 'b'. I don't have the permission of the user 'b'.

Comment: mmm....it confuse me  little. the solution i mentioned generate a single log in that folder. While multiple connections and query are executed they are stored into that. I can't figure why you have such permission issues given the fact that the dbms it's tracking all this information for you (you said to have 777 access..). So if i undertood well if the problem can araise the first time when the log file is created , to avoid permission inheritance you can force the creation of this file so you will have access. Tell me mor about your situation if you think it's different.